# Knockout JS: Observable Array not updating, cannot determine why

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

#### Background

I have a pretty basic application I'm developing as a learning exercise for Knockout. In my view model, I have an observable array of `students`. This object is comprised of many `student`s, which are my model. Each student has an observable array of `scores`. The `scores` array consist of observable numbers that are dynamically pushed to the `scores` array.

The information above describes my intent. Unfortunately, something's breaking, but I cannot decipher where. My console log shows that the values in my array of scores are *not* being updated when I push to the array. It is unclear to me where my logic/methodology is wrong. The lack of updating is most clearly seen when I try to update the average score in the scores` array.

My content, as well as console log, can be accessed here: http://jsbin.com/fehoq/45/edit

#### HTML

```html
<button data-bind="click: addWork">Add New Assignment</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <!-- ko foreach: assignments -->
            <th><input data-bind="value: workName  + ' ' + ($index() + 1)"/></th>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!--<th data-bind=>Overall Grade</th> -->
            <th>Class Grade</th>
        </tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: students">
        <tr>
          <td><input data-bind="value: fullName"/></td>  
            <!-- ko foreach: scores -->  
            <td><input data-bind="value: $data"/></td>
            <!-- /ko --> 
            <td><input data-bind="value: mean" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="remove" data-bind="click: $root.removeStudent.bind($root)". /></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

#### JS

Note that the code below are relevant snippets, not the whole of the application.

**1. Model**

```
var StudentModel = (function () {
    function StudentModel(fullName) {
        var _this = this;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.scores = ko.observableArray();
        this.mean = ko.computed(function (scores) {
            var n = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.scores(), function (score) {
                n += score();
                console.log(n);
            });
            n = n / _this.scores().length;
            return n;
        });
    }
```

...

**2. View Model**

```
function StudentsViewModel() {
    var _this = this;
    this.students = ko.observableArray([
        new Gradebook.Model.StudentModel("Jeff Smith"),
        new Gradebook.Model.StudentModel("Gandalf")
    ]);
    this.assignments = ko.observableArray([
        new Gradebook.Model.WorkModel("Math"),
        new Gradebook.Model.WorkModel("Reading")
    ]);
    this.addStudent = function () {
        this.students.push(new Gradebook.Model.StudentModel(""));
        this.updateRows();
    };
    this.addWork = function () {
        this.assignments.push(new Gradebook.Model.WorkModel("Assignment "));
        this.updateRows();
    };
    this.updateRows = function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.students(), function (student) {
            while (student.scores().length < _this.assignments().length) {
                student.scores.push(ko.observable(100));
            }
        });
    };
}
```

#### Edit

Just as an added note, I spent a reasonable amount of time looking into this at SO but none of the solutions I encountered where helpful for me so far.

Comment: Good point, updating now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `value: $data` in your binding refers to the unwrapped, non-observable *value* of your observable array entry, not the observable itself.

Essentially, this makes this a one-way binding - it reads the initial state, and is then never updated again.

Since Knockout 3.0, you can use `$rawData` instead:

```html
<!-- ko foreach: scores -->  
  <td><input data-bind="value: $rawData"/></td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

From the *[Binding Context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)* documentation:

> **`$rawData`**
>
> This is the raw view model value in the current context. Usually this
>   will be the same as $data, but if the view model provided to Knockout
>   is wrapped in an observable, $data will be the unwrapped view model,
>   and $rawData will be the observable itself.

For reference: [Knockout.js using `value:` binding in a `foreach` over a list of strings - does not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350485/knockout-js-using-value-binding-in-a-foreach-over-a-list-of-strings-does)